# Why is a element position relative inside a table header (th) hidden outside its border?

Tags: html, css

I have a html table and in one of the table headers, I need to have a customized tooltip. So i added a div inside the  that, so that I can style it and make a tooltip. To acheive this, I need to position it as relative, since I want it out of the normal doc flow and make it seem like its hovering on top of the . But when the tooltip extends the table header's border, it tends to disappear. I tried using z-index, but it does't work. How can I resolve this issue and make the tooltip (which is inside the th tag) visible even outside the th's boarder?

HTML:

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
      <tr class="header-row">
         <th>Rank</th>
         <th>Wallet Address</th>
         <th>Avg. Bananas/Game</th>
         <th>Avg. Distance/Game</th>
         <th>Distance Reached</th>
         <th>World Reached</th>
         <th style="
            z-index: 100;
            position: relative;
            ">
            <div class="multiplier-col">Multiplier <img src="/static/media/info_icon.af5a2d2b.svg" alt="info" class="header-icon"></div>
            <span class="tooltip" style="
               /* z-index: 10; */
               position: absolute;
               ">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </span>
         </th>
         <th>$PRIMATE Token Earned</th>
         <div class="table-heading-background"></div>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: can u share html?

Comment: What is providing the CSS? And it looks at first glance as though the tooltip is positioned absolute, not relative as in the title. Which is it?